# Rundeck - reboot server job

Tags: jobs, reboot, rundeck

I have a rundeck job that reboots a server, it sends the command "sudo reboot". This works and the server is rebooting.

The problem is that rundeck doesn't get a signal back so the job fails.

Is there a way to make this work and get a complete signal back in rundeck?

Comment: @willemdh Then upvote the question?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps wrap your command in a script, background the reboot operation, and return 0?  I'm doing something similar with a set of development VMs, but I'm using virsh.  I don't see why this couldn't be done with a physical server:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh rundeck@yourserver sudo reboot &
exit 0
```

You may need to experiment a bit with the ssh options (perhaps '-f' and/or '-n') to get this to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Well playing around now I just used as Local Command step:

`ssh ${node.username}@${node.hostname} "reboot & exit"`

The return code is ZERO and everybody is happy.